# Query to find whether first and second positions of a column has numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, wildcard

If I have column which has varchar values like

```
07SNBYDT
20NETHRR
23198BER
12837930
BEYTRETY
1245YHTY
```

In the above values i just need only entries which have  has digits in **first** and **second** position  and a letter in **third** position
For example: **07**SNBYDT

**My Expected output is**

```
07SNBYDT
20NETHRR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where col like '[0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Col
FROM Table
WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(Col, 0, 1)) > XX AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(Col, 0, 1)) < YY 
AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(Col, 1, 1)) > XX AND ASCII(SUBSTRING(Col, 1, 1)) < YY
AND (ASCII(SUBSTRING(Col, 2, 1)) < XX OR ASCII(SUBSTRING(Col, >, 1)) > YY)
```

where XX is ASCII (0) AND YY is ASCII(9)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table 
where isnumeric(substring(col,1,1)) = 1
and isnumeric(substring(col,2,1)) = 1
and substring(col,3,1) LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%'
```